# Calculate DateDiff Challenge Via Pivot Operator

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I am trying to calculate the duration between two different times. Here is my Original query and its results:

```
  SELECT 
      [DJ_NUMBER]
      ,[PROCESSING_ACTION]
      ,[TRANSACTION_QTY]
      ,[MES_MACHINE]
      ,[ACTION]
      ,[ACTION_TIME]
       ,[UNIQUE_ID]
   FROM [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch]
--   where ACTION in ('SetUp Start', 'Run Start','Run End')
    WHERE PROCESSING_ACTION = 'Job Status'
   Order by DJ_NUMBER asc, ACTION_TIME 
[![SourceData][1]][1]
```

[image: SQL Code for the Source data]

I tried to use DateDiff function but I am having conversion issue with it. My 'Run End' and 'Run Start' are string format:
[image]

DATEDIFF(Minute,'Run End','Run Start')
What I need is to get the following via Pivot Operator:
Duration 1 = 'Run Start' - 'SetUp Start' 
Duration 2 = 'Run End' - 'Run Start'

Final Output should be something like this:

DJ_NUMBER   Duration1(Minutes)  Duration2(Minutes)
19483257         0                     50
19483258         0                     4.00

Here is my Pivot table Operator. Here is my code:

```
       SELECT   DJ_NUMBER 
            , 'SetUp Start' as [SetUp]
            ,'Run Start' as [RunStart]
            ,'Run End' as [RunEnd]
--          ,DATEDIFF(Minute,'Run End','Run Start')
   FROM 
   (
        SELECT   DJ_NUMBER,ACTION,ACTION_TIME
        FROM [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch]
   )   As SourceData
   PIVOT
   (
     COUNT( ACTION_TIME)
     FOR  ACTION IN ([SetUp Start], [Run Start],[Run End])
   ) AS PIVOTTABLE
   Order by DJ_NUMBER asc

[![PivotOperaot Code][4]][4]
```

Any help will to calculate the duration in a pivot table will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you..

Comment: What is the format of Run End and Run Start dates?

Comment: String (VARCHAR)

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answers my question, I was able to figure it out myself. Here is the solution for anyone who is interested:

```
SELECT 
     A.MES_MACHINE AS LineNo
    ,A.DJ_NUMBER
    ,A.ACTION as SetupStarted
    ,A.ACTION_TIME AS SetupStart
    ,B.ACTION as RunStarted
    ,B.ACTION_TIME AS UpTimeStart
    ,C.ACTION as RunEnded
    ,C.ACTION_TIME AS UpTimeEnd
    ,FORMAT(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.ACTION_TIME, B.ACTION_TIME)/60.0,'##.##') AS Setup
    ,FORMAT(DATEDIFF(SECOND, B.ACTION_TIME, C.ACTION_TIME)/60.0, '##.##') AS UpTime
```

FROM [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] A, [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] B, [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] C
WHERE (B.DJ_NUMBER = A.DJ_NUMBER AND B.ACTION_TIME > A.ACTION_TIME) and (C.DJ_NUMBER = B.DJ_NUMBER AND C.ACTION_TIME > B.ACTION_TIME)

Comment: L17 20219539 SetUp Start 2018-10-27 09:11:06.000 Run Start 2018-10-27 09:51:39.000 Run End 2018-10-27 10:24:13.000 40.55 32.57
L17 20379662 SetUp Start 2018-11-20 06:30:17.000 Run Start 2018-11-20 06:48:15.000 Run End 2018-11-20 07:25:20.000 17.97 37.08